# Apache + mod_cband, limit cband-status to certain vhosts and users

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, mod-cband

Is there a way to setup mod_cband to display cband-status for a specific vhost and for a specific user?

What I want to achieve is a status page for a client that if he opens for example: http://www.example.com/cband-status, then he will get a status page for HIS vhost only and not showing any other configurations.

Also how do I make Basic authentication for a certain user per vhost? (different users have access on different vhosts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this example from http://www.howtoforge.com/mod_cband_apache2_bandwidth_quota_throttling_p3:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  CBandLimit 100M
  CBandExceededSpeed 128 5 15
  CBandScoreboard /var/www/scoreboard
  CBandPeriod 4W

  <Location /cband-status>
    SetHandler cband-status
  </Location>
  <Location /cband-status-me>
    SetHandler cband-status-me
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache and check the status pages at http://www.example.com/cband-status and http://www.example.com/cband-status-me

Comment: Works great! The problem with my configuration was that I had the location and handler set globally and not separately in the VirtualHosts. Thanks!